# Locking the database to a single user so that other user wont change it

Tags: sql-server-compact

I am using SQL Server CE 4.0. In office the database (`.sdf`) file are on a server. When I want to change design of the database I have to copy it to local PC and access it since n/w connection to a compact database not allowed.

But when I modify the design of tables I have to be sure that no other user in my office connects to that database and changes the same database. Because I have to again copy the changed database to my server PC and I don't want the design changes made by others. So how can I be sure that no one else connected to the database which I have been editing. Is there any method of locking the database to a single user when I edit the design of the database.

Comment: I feel I must have asked you this before, but you know that CE is deprecated, right? Have you considered SQL Server Express?

Comment: @AaronBertrand is correct, but if you can't: Can you make the db file on the server read-only via the OS? Or just temporarily move it during your modifications to an alt location?

Comment: @JohnM  My problem is not preventing users from using it on server PC(server pc folder has restriction permission). When i copy it to local PC to edit and change designs some one else may connect and change something.

Comment: If you can't connect to the database over the network then how would someone else access the file on your PC?

Comment: @JohnM I have mentioned in my question that "when I modify the design of tables I have to be sure that no other user in my office connects to that database and changes the same database". Before that i have mentioned that i have to copy it to local pc and edit it. So my problem is if anyone connects to the database which is on local pc. There can be more than one user from same PC accessing over remote desktop who can connect to same database. they are not considered as n/w users.

Comment: How would people know to go looking on this "local PC" if the server is not currently working? If its local, temporarily disable multiple remote logins...or just put the database file in folder where they do not have permission to access. This really shouldn't be so hard.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the database file a read-only during the schema change, or run the schema change as sql commands from your app.

Comment: If I make the database read-only then how can I change it's schema? My problem is not preventing users from using it on server PC(server pc folder has restriction permission). When i copy it to local PC to edit and change designs some one else may connect and change something.

Comment: Make the database on the file server read-only!

Comment: How to edit the datbase if it made read-only?

Comment: WAT - Edit the local writeable copy, and make the one on the file server read-only while you do that...